# How many integers are there between 50 and 250 inclusive which are congruent to 1 mod 7?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Number of integers between $50$ and $250$ inclusive which are congurent to $1$ mod $7$.

I understand that one could find the smallest and largest numbers in the interval $[50,250]$ that are congruent to $1$ mod $7$: $50$ $(=7 \cdot 7 + 1)$ and $246$ $(=7 \cdot 35 + 1)$ respectively, and I'm told that all that is left to do is subtract $7$ from $35$ and add $1$ ($29$), but I am unsure why exactly the $1$ is added.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the list of consecutive integers from $m$ to $n$ (inclusive) is $n-m+1$.

To see this, think about "$1,2,3$". The entries are their own position numbers, so the last entry is the total number of positions (the length of the list).

If you scoot this list forward by five, you have "$6,7,8$". The integer *before* the first entry tells how far you have "scooted"--in this case, the integer is "$5$" (the integer before "$6$"). So to get the length, subtract the "scoot" from the last entry: length = $8 - 5 = 3$.

So you can see that if the consecutive integers are "$m,m+1,m+2,...,n$", then the last entry is $n$, and the integer *before* the first entry is $m-1$, so the length = $n-(m-1) = n-m+1$.

Answer (score 0):

If the interval were very short, and the first and last numbers were the same, the difference would be zero, so you add 1.

If the first and last numbers were consecutive multiples of 7 - so there are two of them, 201*7+1 and 202*7+1, then 202-201=1, and again you add 1 to get 2.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<k\le m$. Then there is 1 number in (0, m] which is $k\pmod m$, two numbers in (0, 2m] which are $k\pmod m$, etc. Since the smallest is $k$ itself, there are $\left\lfloor\frac{x+(m-k)}{m}\right\rfloor$ such numbers up to $x$. Thus there are $\left\lfloor\frac{250+6}{7}\right\rfloor$ numbers = 1 mod 7 up to 250 and $\left\lfloor\frac{49+6}{7}\right\rfloor$ up to 49 and the difference is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well $7*7+1$ is the smallest number that gives $1\pmod{7}$ and is between $50\leq x\leq250$
So there are only 6 numbers out of 35 that aren't in the interval

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $a_n=7n+1$. You have found that all the terms from $a_7$ through $a_{35}$ work and now all that remains is to count how many terms this actually is.

Hence we wish to count the number of integers $x$ such that $x\in[7,35]$ note that this is the same number of integers as in the range $[7-6,35-6]=[1,29]$, so the answer is clearly $29$.

Intuitively, we add $1$ because we wish to count both endpoints, and not just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Take 'S' as the set of all integers from 50 to 250 inclusive.

We have done the first half of the problem by figuring out the smallest number in 'S' is 50 and largest number is 246. There should be no doubt here.

Notice that to get from one term in 'S' to the next consecutive one, you simply add seven. Both terms will be (a multiple of seven + 1). We can set up an arithmetic sequence using this.

Nth term = First term + (n – 1)(common difference).

246 = 50 + (n-1)(7)

196 = 7(n-1)

n = 29.

Hence there are 29 terms in the sequence and there is our answer.